# PostgreSQL get results that have been created 24 hours from now

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have two tables that I am joining together.  I want to filter the results based on whether or not it had been created 24 hours prior.  Here are my tables.

```
table user_infos (
  id integer,
  date_created timestamp with timezone,
  name varchar(40)
);

table user_data (
  id integer,
  team_name varchar(40)
);
```

This is my query that I am using to join them together and hopefully filter them:

```
SELECT timestampdiff(HOUR, user_infos.date_created, now()) as hours_since,
       user_data.id, user_data.team_name,
       user_infos.name, user_infos.date_created
       FROM user_data
           JOIN user_infos      
               ON user_infos.id=user_data.id  
       WHERE timestampdiff(HOUR, user_infos.date_created, now()) < 24 
       ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC  
       LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

What I am trying to do is join the two tables such that the id, team_name, name, and date-created would be treated as one table.
Then I would like to filter it such that I only get the results that were created 24 hours ago.  This is what I am using the timestampdiff for.
Then I ORDER then by name and id in ascending order.
then limit the results to 50.

Everything look good except that I doesn't work.  When I run this query it tells me that the "hour" column does not exist.

Clearly there is something subtle here that is messing everything up.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

Alternatively, I've tried this, but it tells me that there is a syntax error at 1;

```
SELECT
    user_data.id, user_data.team_name,
    user_infos.name, user_infos.date_created
    FROM user_data
        JOIN user_infos 
            ON user_infos.id=user_data.id  
    WHERE user_infos.date_created
          BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ) AND 
           DATE ( NOW() ) 
    ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC 
    LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with your data types.  You are checking if a timestamp field is between a casted date field (which removes the time from the date).  `NOW()` is different than the `DATE(NOW())`.

So you have 2 options.  You can either remove the `DATE()` casting and it should work, or you can cast the date_created to a date.

```
SELECT
    user_data.id, user_data.team_name,
    user_infos.name, user_infos.date_created
FROM user_data
    JOIN user_infos 
        ON user_infos.id=user_data.id  
WHERE user_infos.date_created
      BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND 
       NOW()  
ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bcdcb/7)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but It still doesn't work.  I removed the "DATE" function like you suggested, but the same error appears. (I apologise writing the error message on one line, the new line characters aren't appearing for some reason)

`Error making query
{ [error: syntax error at or near "1"]
  name: 'error',
  length: 84,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '261',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1053',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror' }`

Comment: @Calimari328 -- please reproduce the error in the fiddle I provided and share.

Comment: Ok.  This is embarrassing.  I was told that the DB I was working with was MYSQL, but actually, it is POSTGRESQL.  (no wonder nothing worked, I was using the wrong language). btw  That SQL fiddle website is SO AWESOME! [PGSQL demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3bcdc/2/0)

Comment: Again, thank you for your tips.  I believe I know where to go from here.  Thank you

Comment: @Calimari328 -- :D no worries.  This should help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3bcdc/5 -- And you gotta love the Fiddle!